# Inspecting Machine Instruction in Runtime

Tags: c, linux, assembly, elf

I am trying to print the op code of a function in run time. For that I have written a C program which should print the address and hex data at that address.
Here it tries to print the content of mul function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Adding..\n");
    return a+b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Subtracting...\n");
    return a-b;
}

int mul(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Multiplying...\n");
    return add(a,b) * sub(a,b);
}

int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    int i;
    char a;

    int (*func)(int,int);

    mul(4,3);
    func = &mul;
    ptr = (char *)func;

    do
    {
        a = *ptr;
        printf("%p %x\n",ptr,a);
        ptr++;
    }while (a != 0xffffffc3); 
    //op code for ret is c3, which specifies end of function
    //however, i am not certain why it opcode is being padded by 0xffffff
}
```

It output it gives is

```
Multiplying...
Adding..
Subtracting...
0x4005a4 55
0x4005a5 48
0x4005a6 ffffff89
0x4005a7 ffffffe5
0x4005a8 53
0x4005a9 48
0x4005aa ffffff83
0x4005ab ffffffec
0x4005ac 18
0x4005ad ffffff89
0x4005ae 7d
0x4005af ffffffec
0x4005b0 ffffff89
0x4005b1 75
0x4005b2 ffffffe8
0x4005b3 ffffffbf
0x4005b4 c
0x4005b5 7
0x4005b6 40
0x4005b7 0
0x4005b8 ffffffe8
0x4005b9 63
0x4005ba fffffffe
0x4005bb ffffffff
0x4005bc ffffffff
0x4005bd ffffff8b
0x4005be 55
0x4005bf ffffffe8
0x4005c0 ffffff8b
0x4005c1 45
0x4005c2 ffffffec
0x4005c3 ffffff89
0x4005c4 ffffffd6
0x4005c5 ffffff89
0x4005c6 ffffffc7
0x4005c7 ffffffe8
0x4005c8 ffffff90
0x4005c9 ffffffff
0x4005ca ffffffff
0x4005cb ffffffff
0x4005cc ffffff89
0x4005cd ffffffc3
```

The output is almost as i desired but some op codes are being padded by 0xffffff on the left and are being read as negative values. Why is it so?

The objdump of the ELF file is given below

```
 00000000004005a4 <mul>:
  4005a4:   55                      push   %rbp
  4005a5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005a8:   53                      push   %rbx
  4005a9:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  4005ad:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  4005b0:   89 75 e8                mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
  4005b3:   bf 0c 07 40 00          mov    $0x40070c,%edi
  4005b8:   e8 63 fe ff ff          callq  400420 <puts@plt>
  4005bd:   8b 55 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%edx
  4005c0:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
  4005c3:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  4005c5:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  4005c7:   e8 90 ff ff ff          callq  40055c <add>
  4005cc:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
  4005ce:   8b 55 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%edx
  4005d1:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
  4005d4:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  4005d6:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  4005d8:   e8 a1 ff ff ff          callq  40057e <sub>
  4005dd:   0f af c3                imul   %ebx,%eax
  4005e0:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  4005e4:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  4005e5:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005e6:   c3                      retq
```

The hex codes are almost the same, except the padding of 0xffffff. I am not being able to figure out why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because on your system, `char` is signed. Use `unsigned char` instead, or (as suggested in a comment) `uint8_t` if you're on a C implementation that has it.

Also, since you can't portably convert a function pointer to `void *`, I don't think you can portably assume that a function pointer points at readable memory which holds the function's representation in machine code.

I realize it's *typical* and somewhat logical, but I don't think C guarantees it. In that case, this program will trigger undefined behavior. Hopefully it won't do anything harmful, and still be instructive (pun intended).

Comment: Or even better, the standardized 8-bit unsigned integer type `uint8_t`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `uint8_t` is entirely useless - anywhere it exists, `unsigned char` must *also* be an 8-bit unsigned integer type.

Comment: @caf uint8_t - if it exists - is guaranteed to be an unsigned 8 bit quantity.  It's better to use it than one of the types with an implicit width if only to document the code better.

Comment: @caf No. `unsigned char` must be an unsigned type of `CHAR_BIT` bits in width.

Comment: @caf: `uint8_t` is anything but useless. It makes it explicit that you are handling an 8-bit unsigned integer, i.e. a number, whereas `unsigned char` hints at character handling, which might or might not mean the same, semantically.

Comment: @unwind Although you are correct, portability is not an issue in this case because the code is clearly designed to work only with 8 bit opcodes on a machine that has `0xc3` as the opcode that ends the function.  That means we are almost certainly talking about only x86 based architectures.

Comment: @unwind It might be worthwhile to back "*I don't think you can portably assume that a function pointer points at readable memory which holds the function's representation in machine code.*" up with an actual implementation. Consider [Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/) or [CINT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint), as these aren't compilers, they're unlikely to point function pointers at any meaningful machine code.

Comment: While `unsigned char` is 8 bit on most systems, this is not necessarly the case (`CHAR_BIT` may also be 16 for example).

Comment: @JeremyP I agree that portability is quite obviously not the *goal* of this code, but I find it useful to point out when people are doing things that are on (or across) the edge of what is OK, so to speak.

Comment: @JeremyP This code is equally likely to malfunction on uncommon implementations running on x86 systems as it is to malfunction on non-x86 implementations. It's not just unportable. It's undefined behaviour. It's *not* C.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Anywhere that `uint8_t` exists, `CHAR_BIT` must be equal to 8.  This is because `char` is the smallest directly addressable object, `CHAR_BIT` is constrained to be at least 8, and `uint8_t` must have exactly 8 bits.

Comment: @caf The point of `uint8_t` is to break when that typedef *doesn't* exist, presumably because it *can't*. Thus, it isn't useless.